# Python next() function fails while __next__ works on file?

Tags: python

I was studying *Mark Lutz's* book on python called "*Learning Python (5th Ed)*". While perusing chapter 14 on *Iteration and Comprehensions* , I faced a problem in page 423.

There, we have created a file object returned by `os.popen()` call. It is an iterable object (has `__iter__` method) but not an iterator (no `__next__` method). So, this object should be called by neither `next()` built-in function nor `__next__` method call. But somehow this object returns values on next dunder method call but raise exception on next() builtin calls.

In the book, the author said it is unusual. But he didn't provide any explanation for that.

Can anyone explain me how `__next__` succeeds for that file-like object?

```
import os
file = os.popen("ls -l")
print(dir(file)) # this shows __iter__ but no __next__/ next
# print(next(file)) # this fails if uncommented, expected
print(file.__next__()) # this does NOT fail even there is no __next__
```

Similar code for a list that behaves as I expect:

```
file = [1]
print(dir(file)) # this shows __iter__ but no __next__/ next
# print(next(file)) # this fails if uncommented, expected
# print(file.__next__()) # this fails if uncommented, expected
```

Comment: Interesting.  When I run this in 3.12, there is a `__next__` method, but I still get the strange behavior you mention.  `next(file)` gives an error while `file.__next__()` works fine.

Comment: And to answer @AlexeiLevenkov's question. I just typed `file = os.popen("ls -l")`.  This does appear to contradict the documentation that `next(x)` just calls `x.__next__()`.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next

Comment: You probably need to do `iter` on it first. Also, what's the exception?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, that Q&A does not explain this behaviour.

Comment: `__next__` is [found through `__getattr__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.1/Lib/os.py#L1023) for this object. As usual for this kind of thing, `next` bypasses `__getattr__`.

Comment: I actually think that OP's question is a good question.  next() is documented to call __next__().  In this case, it isn't.  He wants to know why that is the case.  So do I.

Comment: In the commented out examples, you're calling `file.next()`, which won't ever exist (in Python 3). Did you mean to write `next(file)`?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes. That's what i have tried to say. Sorry for not being clear. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @Blckknght yes. That should be `next(file)` for python 3

Answer (score 4):

`os.popen` returns a file-like proxy object, an instance of a `_wrap_close` helper class. This helper class implements `__iter__`, but it does not implement `__next__`. However, it *does* implement `__getattr__`, forwarding unknown attribute lookup to the underlying object it wraps:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    return getattr(self._stream, name)
```

When you call `__next__` manually, `__getattr__` forwards the lookup to the underlying object, the `stdout` stream of a `subprocess.Popen` instance, and this object has a `__next__` method. However, `next` bypasses `__getattr__`. As a general principle, when Python needs to look up a special method to implement a core language feature or built-in function, it bypasses `__getattr__`, `__getattribute__`, and the instance dict, and directly searches the object's class and ancestor classes for the method.

There are a few exceptions to that principle, but it usually applies, and this is not one of the exceptions. Since the `_wrap_close` helper does not have an implementation of `__next__`, `next` raises an exception.